# Как внутри UILabel отобразить текст с учетом html тэгов?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[stringFromHtml dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    self.textLabel.attributedText = attrString;
    self.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14.0];
```

Функция `\r\n`, `\t` и `<br>` понимает, а вот bold `<b> </b>` и italic `<i> </i>` - понимать отказывается (игнорирует).

Comment: почему бы вручную не распарсить болд и италик?

Comment: у меня ваш код отработал отлично. может кодировку попробуйте поменять на UTF8

Comment: Менял... жирным текст не выделяет, с италиком та же беда

Comment: Я так понял, невозможно без сторонних библиотек сделать такое в оригинальном UILabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот эта строка

```
self.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14.0];
```

переопределяет все ваши `<b>` и `<i>`, т.к. в ios для стилей текста используются сами шрифты.

Для изменения шрифта используйте категорию:
https://gist.github.com/funkydevil/aff16a6c94dff283960b

Вот пример:

```
-(void)testFunction
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,50,self.view.frame.size.width,30)];
    [self.view addSubview:label];


    NSString *myString = @"<b>BOLD</b> <i>ITALIC</i> REGULAR";

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString;
    attributedString = [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                        options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                             NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:@(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                             documentAttributes:nil
                                                          error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [attributedString setFontButSaveStyle:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:30.0]];

    label.attributedText = attributedString;

}
```